# Ignore white spaces during comparison with values from httpResponse in Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, httpresponse

I have written a Groovy script to extract the value of the city from the Map of HTTP Response where fruit should be the value obtained in variable f and color should be the value obtained in the variable c. Assume that values of f and c are correctly obtained through some method. If you see carefully in the HTTP response, there an extra white space in the beginning of the color " Red", and there is an extra white space at the end of color "yellow ". There are also extra white spaces in fruit names. This is hampering my comparison. How can I make sure that the white spaces in the beginning and at the end of words in HTTP response are ignored during the comparison?

```
{
    "userInformation": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Location": "India"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "fruit": "Apple  ",
            "color": " Red",
            "city": "New Delhi",
            "luckyNumber": 10
        },
        {
            "fruit": "Banana ",
            "color": "yellow ",
            "city": "Goa",
            "luckyNumber": 12
         }
         ]
         }
```

Here's the code I am using -

```
def f = execution.getVariable("Fruits") 
def c = execution.getVariable("Colors") 
def cityName =httpResponse.json.details.find { it.fruit == f  && it.color == c }?.city
```

Comment: What comparison? You're not comparing value of `city` to anything. But, you could always use `trim()` before comparing, wherever that comparing is taking place.

Comment: @Andreas comparing value of f to fruit and value of c to color. Wherever in the json response, we find correct comparison, we extract city value from there.

Comment: So you're *not* comparing `city`, only `fruit` and `color`, and it is `city`, not `fruit` or `color`, that has whitespace issues, which means you *don't* have any issues in the **comparisons** you're doing. --- If you don't want leading/trailing whitespace in the **extracted** `city` value, simply add `?.trim()` after `}?.city`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for pointing that out. just made edits to the question - there are extra white spaces in the colors and fruits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `s` below is the JSON snippet you provided, then consider (full example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/blob/master/groovy/StackO_52750318/Example.groovy)):

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(s)
def f = 'Apple'
def c = 'Red'

def trimCompare = { a, b ->
    a.trim() == b.trim()
}

def cityName = json.details
                   .find { trimCompare(it.fruit,f) && trimCompare(it.color,c) }
                  ?.city
assert 'New Delhi' == cityName
```

Comment: This is throwing an error - javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.trim() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: wait(), grep(), wait(long), is(java.lang.Object), grep(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter)

Comment: My full example is here - https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/blob/master/groovy/StackO_52750318/Example.groovy (It doesn't throw an error so something must be different between our programs.)